# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Tags: android, google-plus

I have tried to integrate google+ authentication in my android app but got an exception. I have included google-play-services.jar and google-play-services_lib as library project.
I have attached log cat file below

```
   ComponentInfo{com.GenioCode.doodle/com.GenioCode.doodle.Register}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #115: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at com.GenioCode.doodle.Register.onCreate(Register.java:40)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    ... 11 more
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton" on path: /data/app/com.GenioCode.doodle-1.apk
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-24 02:49:44.566: E/AndroidRuntime(12969):    ... 23 more
```

What is the issue here

Comment: apparently your issue is `Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton" on path: /data/app/com.GenioCode.doodle-1.apk` can you verify if it is available?

Comment: i can see the same file in File Explorer /data/app/com.GenioCode.doodle-1.apk

Comment: What do you mean? I mean how can I verify it?

Answer (score -1):

**Here is how to fix the problem**

1. Import google-play-services_lib, which i think you have already done.
2. Now add google-paly-services.jar file here is how to do it. 
   Right click on your working project and select **Build Path -> Configure Build Path**. Select the Libraries tab and on the right click the Add External Jars. Browse to ADT-Eclipse folder 
   -> sdk -> extras -> google -> google_paly_services -> libprojet -> google-play-services_lib -> lib
3. Clear your project by clicking menu Projects -> clean.

Hope this help.

Comment: Didn't help at all. Still have the problem.